# programming for a generic ARM environment in C or C++ on X86

Tags: c, arm, emulation, abi

I'm looking for a solution to begin my journey in the ARM world's, i want to use the C as my main language and i'd like to create a basic program using the standard I/O library for this environment.

Also, there is an emulator or something like that which runs on an X86 based PC?  I can try some operative systems on this kind of emulator like Debian for ARM?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you don't have any specific hardware platform in mind already, then [QEMU](http://wiki.qemu.org/Main_Page) might be working for the emulation part.

Comment: what do you mean with "specific hardware platform" ? And if i cared to?

Comment: @Micro If you have some hardware that you may want to use in the future, you should check with the manufacturer if they have an emulator for that hardware. Will make it much simpler to port your application when it's time to move to the real hardware. If you don't plan to run on hardware, then QEMU should do fine.

Comment: it's not possible to run qemu with a specific profile? I mean, considering that qemu is a generic emulator, it's not possible to customize its behaviour?

Comment: @Micro It should have a large set of plugable devices, if that's what you mean. But I have personally only used it briefly a few years ago.

Comment: not exactly, i was wondering if can be possible to run qemu with an ARMv11 profile instead of, for say, ARMv8.

Comment: @Micro I don't know, but I would guess so. Check the documentation.

Answer (score 0):

For the sake of completeness: [Skyeye](http://sourceforge.net/apps/phpwebsite/skyeye/) might be an alternative to QEMU, although it does not seem as well documented (at least not in english).